# Why would a country be involuntarily involved in stealing prototype weapons of another allied one?

Tags: politics, diplomacy, espionage, criminal-underworld, terrorism

I want to create a spy story but I lack political or military knowledge to build a solid plot.

France discovers that the prototype of one of his last torpedoes, F21 « Artémis », has been stolen while moving from the torpedo factory in Saint-Tropez. After an accident at the toll booth blocked by the Yellow Vests at La Ciotat, the gendarmerie brigade discovers in the trunk of the smashed van a tank of air that is supposed to be in the place of the explosive charge (or the explosive charge itself ). With regard to what they find in the van they leave on the track of a flight from the Libyan rebellion to sink the government fleet (the driver was a former British agent or an informer?).

However, finally the gendarmes conclude that it might be the British. They would want France to be responsible, pay the heavy past of their cooperation during the civil war of Libya. In truth it will be an internal betrayal of a nationalist admiral who has all committed to France back to power.

The problem is that I can not justify the passage when the Gendarmerie thinks it is Libyan responsibilities to the British's. Especially since in the end it is not their responsibility.

**Why would a country be involuntarily involved in stealing prototype weapons of another allied one ?**

I thought about :
 - A former or actual British spy. But if it is a spy who stole the torpedo, then why would he do it as far as the countries are allies ? For money to sell it to the Lybian rebels ? But what would be the reason 
 - An informant
 - industries ?

Comment: This sounds like our world.  You need plot help.  It is an interesting question but not really world building.  I leave you with my dad's thought:  people do what they do for 1 of 3 reasons - sex, money or family.

Comment: @willk Nations don't have the same needs or desires as individuals, so 'sex, money, & family' likely don't apply.

Comment: A spy stealing secrets from an allied nation could be a valid question, but there is a lot of situational story telling in this question which I would say makes this too story based to answer. You seem to be pushing a certain scenario , aka France needs to suspect Britain, when in reality is another Frenchman who did the job and somehow the Libyan Rebellion ties into this?

Comment: @ArkensteinXII true, but countries are led by people so Will's comment may well still be valid, depending on whether the involuntary aspect of the espionage benefits or protects the state, or benefits or protects influential decision makers for the state.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this merely requires the OP to read some current affairs news or history books.  There's no WB here.  As a matter of *routine* literally *every* country tries to spy on *every* other country (and in all (?) cases on their own citizens as well).

Comment: Hello Passenger.  Could you explain what rule of your world you are talking about?  Please remember that world building is about rules and systems - defining a world wherein many stories may be told.  Storybuilding (which is off-topic) is about circumstances, actions, and plot.  As written, this sounds like storybuilding, not world building. Can you help us out?

Comment: Just a thought Passenger, have you considered that no nation tends to admit to spying on another, friendly or enemy, so the other nations don't need to be involved, they just have to appear to be, and a high ranking Frenchman should have enough contacts to plant evidence suggesting person A (hapless British tourist) is actually a spy, Britain will says he's not, but they'd say that even if he was so for the purpose of the plot it still works, there is some political ramifications for this but those could be explained away

Answer (score 5):

The is real world examples of allied spies stealing secret technology and passing it off to local companies.  Just because the countries are allies doesn't mean they don't spy on each other and compete competitively

> In 1999, Enercon, a German company and leading manufacturer of wind energy equipment, developed a breakthrough generator for wind turbines. After applying for a US patent, it had learned that Kenetech, an American rival, had submitted an almost identical patent application shortly before. By the statement of a former NSA employee, it was later discovered that the NSA had secretly intercepted and monitored Enercon's data communications and conference calls and passed information regarding the new generator to Kenetech. As German intelligence services are forbidden from engaging in industrial or economic espionage, German companies are frequently complaining that this leaves them defenceless against industrial espionage from the United States. According to Wolfgang Hoffmann, a former manager at Bayer, German intelligence services are aware which companies are being targeted by US intelligence agencies, but refuse to inform the companies involved.

see [ECHELON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECHELON)